# Any idea how can I Insert a table (with rows and Columns) in word using Sikulix command?

Tags: sikuli

Any idea how can I Insert a table (with rows and Columns) in word using Sikulix command? I am able to do till insert table but not able select the rows and columns. Neither Take screenshot nor Insert image is working. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks

Always struck with:

```
[error] script [ Existing ] stopped with error in line 7
[error] FindFailed ( 1623931201601.png: (26x42) in R[0,0 1536x864]@S(0) ) though the image exists
```

Comment: The error you are getting suggests that you are failing to find something on the screen but your question is about inserting. Can you please review your question? It is unclear when the problem occurs.

Comment: You need to be sure ui element is present before acting on it. Look at wait() function